# Multiline not displaying properly with less than 4 lines

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I have a multiline label which works well with word wrapping. However, if i added "\n" to add a new line to the label, it would only display properly if there is 4 lines.

This is how it would look like if has only 3 lines
[image]

And this is how it would look like if it has at least 4 lines
[image]

And this is my constrains my for label

[image]

Comment: How do you set up the number of lines for the label?

Comment: @DávidPásztor Number of lines set to 0

Comment: What are the other views that the label is pin to at the moment?

Comment: Did you get a chance to try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a question in the comments that would help me answer this more completely but without knowing the full storyboard setup you could change the Bottom constraint to >= 3 instead of = to allow the label to resize to the intrinsic height so that the text looks the way you desire.